# Make Spiral Image View using recyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

How to make Spiral Image View using recyclerView in Android as shown in below Image
[image]

I would like to create a spiral image view list as given in the image above using recycler view , where I can add a list of images from my library so as to look like the image above.
The part which I tried is given below, which didn't worked fine as per my requirement.

```
class ArcLayoutManager(private val context: Context, 
           private var horizontalOffset: Int = 0 ) : RecyclerView.LayoutManager() {
  override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams(): RecyclerView.LayoutParams =
           RecyclerView.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
  override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean = true
  override fun scrollHorizontallyBy(dx: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, 
           state: RecyclerView.State?): Int {
           horizontalOffset += dx
           fill(recycler, state)
           Log.d("",""+dx)
           return dx
  }
  override fun scrollVerticallyBy(dy: Int,recycler:RecyclerView.Recycler?,state: RecyclerView.State?): Int {
          Log.d("",""+dy)
          return dy
  }
  override fun onLayoutChildren(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
          super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state)
          Log.d("","$recycler  $state")
          fill(recycler, state)
  }
  private fun fill(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state:
          RecyclerView.State?) {
          detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler ?: return)
          for (itemIndex in 0 until itemCount) {
               val view = recycler.getViewForPosition(itemIndex)
                                            addView(view)
               val viewWidth = pxFromDp(context, 90f)
               val viewHeight = pxFromDp(context, 90f)
               val left = (itemIndex * viewWidth) - horizontalOffset
               val right = left + viewWidth
               val top = computeYComponent((left + right) / 2, viewHeight)
               val bottom = top.first + viewHeight
               val alpha = top.second
               view.rotation = (alpha * (180 / PI)).toFloat() - 90f
               measureChildWithMargins(view, viewWidth.toInt(), viewHeight.toInt())
               layoutDecoratedWithMargins(view,
                               left.toInt(),
                               top.first,
                               right.toInt(),
                               bottom.toInt())
          }     
          recycler.scrapList.toList().forEach {
                   recycler.recycleView(it.itemView)
          }
  }
  
  private fun computeYComponent(viewCenterX: Float,h: Float): <Int,Double> {
    val screenWidth = context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
    val s = screenWidth.toDouble() / 2
    val radius = (h * h + s * s) / (h * 2)
    val xScreenFraction = viewCenterX.toDouble() / screenWidth.toDouble()
    val beta = acos(s / radius)
    val alpha = beta + (xScreenFraction * (Math.PI - (2 * beta)))
    val yComponent = radius - (radius * sin(alpha))
    return Pair(yComponent.toInt(), alpha)
  }
  private fun pxFromDp(context: Context, dp: Float): Float {
     return dp * context.resources.displayMetrics.density
  }
}
```

spiral recyclerview , Can any one can tell me how do I achieve this.

Comment: Hi Mohd! Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check your Question as there is no Image attached and also please provide some code that you have tried out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using custom layout manager with recycler view.

Check this [link](https://github.com/dyguests/LinLayoutManager/blob/master/README_CustomTutorial.md) for more details about how to move items in a custom path
and [this](https://github.com/gagansmartdata/SpiralLayoutManager) for spiral like path example.

Usage will be quiet easy (same as we add any other layout manager):

```
val curveLayoutManger = CurveLayoutManger(ACurve(),this)
              recyclerView.layoutManager = curveLayoutManger
              recyclerView.adapter = Adapter()
```

Hope it help!!